# android - broadcast handle app package change(uninstall)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, uninstallation

i need to handle app package change, i write my mainfest like that

mainfest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="PackageChangeReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
        <data android:scheme="package"/>
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

my receiver class

```
public class PackageChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            System.out.println("app changed thank you ");
        // here i will handle each one as i like

      //if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED")) 
       // do some thing etc

    }

}
```

but i dosnt work , i install , delete broadcast not notified

please help me to fix it 
thank you

Comment: try your code after adding full package name in receiver name

Comment: i try it , its the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok

i compiled your code

its working after adding

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
```

//work for other app uninstalled but dont test by uninstalling this app

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
```

to your code.

you need permissions for package

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```